# Length of special characters in DB2 Warehouse on Cloud

Tags: db2

I have a python script which loads data to a table in DB2 WOC. There is a column which has a type of CHAR(50), and I want to load the following data string to this table:

```
string = "RECOMBINANT ANTI-ERBB 2 ANTIBODY ÝEPR19547-12¨  AL"
```

As you can see there are 2 special characters: `Ý` and `¨`

I checked the length of the string variable in python and it is 50.

However when I wanted to load this string to the table in WOC, it has thrown an error that it is too long:

```
SELECT length('RECOMBINANT ANTI-ERBB 2 ANTIBODY ÝEPR19547-12¨  AL'),
       length('Ý'),
       length('¨')
FROM test.STG_TEST_20220531142326
```

This gives the result of:

```
52 | 2 | 2
```

Which means that these characters are holding 2 positions in DB2 WOC. Can somebody explain why, and is it possible to avoid that?

Comment: in the meantime I found this article, https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=unicode-utfs about different lengths with different encodings, but still not sure how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must declare your column either as `(VAR)CHAR(52)` OR `(VAR)CHAR(50 CODEUNITS32)` to store your string in the  UTF-8 database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there any difference in performance / memory requirement etc. between the 2 solutions?

Comment: Every CODEUNITS32 unit occupies 4 bytes of storage. So, it's 52 vs 200 bytes of storage for CHAR data type. But you may be sure that you are able to store whatever 50 characters as CODEUNITS32 which is obviously not the case for CHAR (50 OCTETS). Default unit setting (if you don't specify `CODEUNITS32` or `OCTETS`) depends on the `string_units` db cfg setting.